# ExtJS 5: how to set up a store to gather remote data when a POST with JSON body is required?

Tags: json, extjs, extjs5, sencha-architect

I need a store to gather data from a URL, but the URL needs a POST of JSON data in order to create the correct response (in this example, a set of disclaimer questions the user must answer, based on the products in his shopping cart.)

Here's what I have so far. I want to send the cart and get the question set in response:

```
QuestionStore: {
            autoLoad: false,
            model: 'RefCig.model.Question',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/refcig-services/questionsForCart',
                actionMethods: {
                    create: 'POST',
                    read: 'POST',
                    update: 'POST',
                    destroy: 'POST'
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json'
                },
                writer: {
                    type: 'json'
                }
            }
        }
```

On submit:

```
var cartStore = Ext.getStore('CartStore');
cartItems = Ext.Array.pluck(cartStore.data.items, 'data');
var questionStore = this.getStore('QuestionStore');
questionStore.load({params:cartItems});
```

A console.log of Ext.encode(cartItems) is exactly what I want to send to the backend:

```
[{
    "id": 19,
    "pricePerUnit": 20,
    "denominationsPerUnit": 1,

    "blahblahblah": 1, 

    "unitQuantity": 1,
    "total_item_count": null,
    "subtotal": 20
}]
```

Yet the request is malformed:

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 19,
        "pricePerUnit": 20,
        "denominationsPerUnit": 1,

        "unitQuantity": 1,
        "total_item_count": null,
        "subtotal": 20
    },
    "page": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "limit": 25
}
```

How should I be telling my QuestionStore to form its request body the way I want?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically your requirement can be met by using a custom proxy. You implement your own `buildRequest` method in there, which is a stripped down version of the [original one](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/source/Server.html#Ext-data-proxy-Server-method-buildRequest):

```
Ext.define('MyProxy', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    alias: 'proxy.my',
    paramsAsJson: true,
    buildRequest: function(operation) {
        var me = this,
            params = operation.getParams(),
            request, operationId, idParam;
        operationId = operation.getId();
        idParam = me.getIdParam();
        if (operationId !== undefined && params[idParam] === undefined) {
            params[idParam] = operationId;
        }
        request = new Ext.data.Request({
            params: params,
            action: operation.getAction(),
            records: operation.getRecords(),
            url: operation.getUrl(),
            operation: operation,
            proxy: me
        });
        request.setUrl(me.buildUrl(request));
        operation.setRequest(request);
        return request;
    }
});
```

Then, in the store definition, you simply use the proxy:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'my',
    // .....
```

---

However, I would recommend another way.

Do something like:

```
questionStore.load({params: {cartItems: cartItems}});
```

instead of

```
questionStore.load({params:cartItems});
```

That will make the request body look like this:

```
{
    "cartItems": [{
        "id": 19,
        "pricePerUnit": 20,
        "denominationsPerUnit": 1,
        "blahblahblah": 1, 
        "unitQuantity": 1,
        "total_item_count": null,
        "subtotal": 20
    }],
    "page": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "limit": 25
}
```

You would need to adjust your server side to retrieve the `cartItems` array from the payload.

Comment: I ended up using a regular Ajax call and populating a Store with a memory proxy via setData. But your explanation of making a custom proxy is the best I've seen and the load idea is good too.